# How to add a fixed item in the jQuery's autocomplete list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple jQuery code to set autocomplete function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  fInitApp();
});

function fInitApp(){
  $("#myList").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    /*.....,*/
    dataType : "json"
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<input name="myList" id="myList">
```

I need to add a separator line to the very bottom of the list with a permanent menu item, i.e.:

```
[sugg    ]
   suggestion 1
   suggestion 2
   suggestion 3
   suggestion 4
   ------------
   my custom link
```

If this bottom item can be added, then can I scroll just suggestion list without bottom item? i.e.:

```
[sugg    ]
        ^
   suggestion 1
   suggestion 2
   suggestion 3
   suggestion 4
        v
   ------------
   my custom link
```

Comment: Can create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the autocomplete's `_renderMenu` method. E.g:

```
/* saves the current behavior of _renderMenu */
var render = $('#myList').autocomplete('instance')._renderMenu;

/* overrides the default method */
$('#myList').autocomplete('instance')._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
  /* adds your fixed item */
  items.push({ label: 'my custom link', value: 'my custom link' });
  /* calls the default behavior again */
  render.call(this, ul, items);
};
```

---

I've made an example for you. Start typing 'co', and you'll see both `COBOL` and `ColdFusion`, but you'll see a fixed last item `ES 2015`. The same will happen, if you start typing 'jav', etc. Take a look:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  fInitApp();
});

function fInitApp() {
  $('#myList').autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ],
    dataType: "json"
  });

  var render = $('#myList').autocomplete('instance')._renderMenu;

  $('#myList').autocomplete('instance')._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
    items.push({
      label: 'ES 2015',
      value: 'ES 2015',
      last: true
    });

    render.call(this, ul, items);
  };

  var renderItem = $('#myList').autocomplete('instance')._renderItem;
  $('#myList').autocomplete('instance')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {    
    if (item.last) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        ul.find('li:last-child').css({
          position: 'fixed',
          top: ul.offset().top + (ul[0].scrollHeight === ul[0].clientHeight ? ul.offset().height : ul[0].clientHeight),
          left: ul[0].style.left,
          width: 'calc(145px - 1.4em)',
          border: '1px solid #CCC',
          borderTop: '2px solid #999',
          backgroundColor: '#FFEFFE'
        });
      }, 0);
    }

    return renderItem.call(this, ul, item);
  };
}
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
  max-height: 125px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input name="myList" id="myList">
```

Comment: Thank you.. It works really good.. But I really need to style that last item either by adding separator line or by coloring or font change.

Comment: That's easy, you can override the `_renderItem` method to achieve that.

Comment: @VladP Np, man! If my answer was useful for you, please upvote it! :)

Comment: well, there is a problem when the list has a scroll bar.. So the last item "ES 2015" is hidden. So look at my initial question. I need to show that "ES 2015" regardless of scroll bar

Comment: @VladP can't you insert it as the first item?

Comment: OK.. will do that.. that may work.. But I wanted it to be like an attachment to the list.. at the bottom.. and scroll just a list.. and this last item should be always visible..

Comment: @VladP I've done an workaround, so, take the time to understand it, and then, edit to make it look like the way you want! And if my answer was useful for you, please, mark it as the accepted one. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "response" event. For more info see
https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

```
//add option in autosuggest list, that would be shown on every search even if search result is null.
$("#myList").autocomplete({
    response: function (event, ui) {
        ui.content.push({ label: "my custom link", value: "my custom link"});
    }
});
```